# Use Arrays from Database for str_replace($search, $replace, $string) - with dynamic values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, str-replace

If I define the array inline in my source code it works. But how can i use var-names from a database?

While I developed this code, I use a inline defined array. But now I want to get the `$search` and `$replace` elements from the database.

**My problem**: `{var}` is not longer replaced with the value of `$var`, but with the string `"$var"`.

```
$template_tags = array(
    '{order_id}',
    '{customer_id}'
);

$replacements = array(
    $insert_id,
    $mail_customer_id
);

// works: str_replace($template_tags, $replacements, $source) is for example "The Customer 0123 has the Order-ID 0987"
```

But if I get `$template_tags` and `$replacements` (ONLY the var names, the var-values are set before in the sourcecode) from the Database the result is:

```
"The Customer $mail_customer_id has the Order-ID $insert_id"
```

My goal is that I can get the var-names from the database, and they are replaced with the - before defined - values

My DB result is:

```
Array ( [0] => {order_id} 
        [template_tag] => {order_id} 
        [1] => $order_id 
        [replacement] => $order_id ) 
Array ( [0] => {customer_id} 
        [template_tag] => {customer_id} 
        [1] => $customer_id 
        [replacement] => $customer_id )
```

**edit:**

This code brings the result I wanted - but it doesn't look very elegant and I **don't want** to use `eval` as it is risky:

```
while ($value = mysqli_fetch_array($replacement_tags_query)) {
    $replacements[] = $value['replacement'];
    $template_tags[] = $value['template_tag'];
}
$str = str_replace($template_tags, $replacements, $testtext);
eval ("\$str = \"$str\";");
echo $str;
```

Comment: Show us your getting stuff from the database code. Most likely you did not replicate the structure of those arrays accurately; use `var_dump` to verify that if you are not sure.

Comment: That's what i get from the database:

`   Array
    (
        [0] => {order_id}
        [template_tag] => {order_id}
        [1] => $order_id
        [replacement] => $order_id
    )  
    Array
    (
        [0] => {customer_id}
        [template_tag] => {customer_id}
        [1] => $customer_id
        [replacement] => $customer_id
    ) `

Comment: Please edit this into your question and format it properly, this is hardly readable in a comment.

Comment: Notice your DB returns `order_id` as `$order_id` and not `$insert_id` in your example (so the `customer_id` is different). More ever, the data return from the DB is string so you basically replace the template with string and no the actual value - you can use this to extract the value: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @dWinder your link to the php-manual was the solution! Thanks!

Comment: @DanielHüpenbecker in order to have this site easy to use it is better to write your solution as answer and not in the question - I edit your post to make it more clearer and post my answer as "answer'' - now you can accepted it (marking the "v" at the left of my answer) so it shown this helped you and resolve your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice your value return from DB are string: as `'$order_id'` so they are not evaluate in the code.

If you want to have the value set dynamically you can use [PHP variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) abilities. So all you need is to remove the `'$'` sign from you DB and do something like:

```
while ($value = mysqli_fetch_array($replacement_tags_query))
{
    $replacements[] = ${$value['replacement']};
    $template_tags[] = $value['template_tag'];
}
```

Now you can use this with: `str_replace($template_tags, $replacements, $string)`

Comment: That's exactly what i did with your help. And it solves my problem.